# How can I change the color of a dashed line in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, line-art

I have a white line. When I switch from basic to dashed line 1.1, the line turns gray. Paintbucketing the line just makes it a basic line again. Based on all the settings I'm aware of, the line should be white, but it seems to arbitrarily change to a gray color when I choose any other type of line that isn't basic.

[image]

[image]

The first shows a basic white line, and the second shows what happens when I switch from basic to dashed line 1.1. The second is a closeup of the dashed gray line in case it would have been hard to see otherwise.

Comment: Greetings! It would be of great help to us all if you edited your question to include some images. Is the problem that you only have either white or grayscale available? No colours?

Comment: The document color mode is RGB and since I'm trying to make a white line, that probably isn't important anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure how you making dashlines/strokes , so here I'm writing here in detail so things get done easily.

I am going to draw out a circle on Illustrator. Of course yours doesn’t have to be a circle. Select the shape Now go to your `STROKE` panel and you should see settings. If you don’t see the `STROKE` panel in your document then go to `WINDOW > STROKE` and it should appear right away.

Now what you have to do is click on the `DASHED LINE` box and check it off. And then you can adjust the dash length and the gap length in the boxes. You can get really specific or just repeat the numbers.

Now if you want to edit this, you can. Go to `OBJECTS > PATHS > OUTLINE STROKE`. This will turn the stroke into an editable object with anchor points.

Now get the white arrow tool and select the area where you want to edit or remove.

Thanks , let me know if you need more help

Comment: All that did was make a dashed white line with gray between the dashes. As before, all other settings indicate the line should be white but it is gray when set to anything other than a basic line. I'm not sure what other information is significant in my problem because nothing looks unusual and I've never had this problem before.

Comment: @EmilyS You need to explain "dashed white line with gray between the dashes" Dashed strokes in Illustrator don't add an "in between" color.. so you've constructed something which is non-standard.

Comment: Here's a screencap of that. http://imgur.com/GcLOOC8
This is what happened when I tried Mohsin's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The solution i found was to change the properties of the dashed line.

1. Select the dashed line with the selection tool (V)
2. in the Path toolbar go to brush definition(the one with a dropbox showing the dashed line), select the dashed line and open options of selected object.
3. Change colorization method to tints, OK
4. Now change the color of the outline as you wish.

[image: illustrator cc screen]

[image: Change colorization method to tints and hit OK]

Answer (score 0):

Create a basic white line - click stroke[image: illustrator screen shot]

Then check the dashed line box

Answer (score -2):

Simple just use a CMYK swatch an the color will change

Comment: Please what is a swatch and how is it to be used?  Your one-line-answer is a little bit short ...